# How to use Multiple versions of Node on a single machine?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, version-control

I am tasked to update the node version for a huge repository which is currently v14.18.0, what is the best way I can go about doing that with minimal version issues with packages and node?

Comment: [Node Version Manager?](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install NVM to install multiple version of node and switch between them :
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 0):

**Using Homebrew - Mac OS**

Install the **Node Version Manager** (NVM) with Homebrew. Run the below command in your terminal:

```
brew install nvm
```

After the installation finishes, open your profile file (nano ~/.bash_profile, or nano ~/.zshrc, or nano ~/.profile, or nano ~/.bashrc), and add the following lines to it at the end:

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

By adding the above lines to your profile page, you can run the nvm command in your terminal. If you don't add the above lines, you will get an error when you run nvm commands in the terminal. Going further, you need to restart your terminal to use the nvm commands in the terminal.

Also, run this command `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`

If in a new terminal nvm doesn't work then try adding this in ~/.zshrc by using this command `nano ~/.zshrc`

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
. "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"
```

**NVM commands**

Now that you have NVM installed, let's see some of the most useful commands.

```
nvm ls
```

nvm ls shows all the versions.

```
nvm use
```

**E.g** `nvm use v20.6.0`

Install the new version suppose node version 20.

```
nvm install 20
```

After installing the Node version you want, you can use it by running the following command:

```
nvm alias default <node_version>

nvm use
```

***After nvm use, you can check the version:***

```
node -v
```

By running above command, nvm switches the Node version to the one you specified.

Answer (score -1):

Install nvm to achieve it.
For macOS kindly follow:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W0CssX7oYmQ

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32398656)